# Decimal to sign and magnitude conversion

Tags: algorithm, math, decimal, computer-science, bit

I've got a question which i have solved and many other similar ones which i have successfully completed as part of my assignment. I am having a little confusion with one of the question which is...

"The decimal number -256 is held in a 9 bit memory location. represent this in sign and magnitude."

the answer that i got is... 11 0000 0000

how i got this is by doing the following:

We first show the binary form and then invert the most significant bit (the bit on the far left. O represents a positive value and 1 represents a negative value) the sign determines whether it is a positive or negative value and the magnitude is the total of the numbers or total of bits etc.

Notice that I’ve added an extra bit to show the representation of -256 in sign and magnitude. This is simply because 9 bits are not enough to show whether 256 is negative or positive as it maxed out. The total of 9 bits gave the magnitude which is 256 and the 10th bit (on the far left) shows the sign which is ‘1’ and this shows that it is a negative 256.

What i find confusing is that the decimal -256 was held in a 9 bit memory location and the result i got was 1 0000 0000. i have added an extra bit to show that the number is negative which then represents it in 10 bit. I am having difficulty with how i can represent -256 in sign and magnitude using only 9 bit. it seems impossible to show in 9 bit and i have therefore used 10 bit but i am only allowed to use 9 bits. could someone help with how this could be achieved. your help will be greatly appreciated. I am just a bit stuck with this. My tutors expect us to use the internet or self knowledge and would not give us even a clue. so that's why i am here.

Comment: Two's complement has the interesting feature that the range of numbers is always from positive N to negative (N+1).  That is, a signed byte will represent from 127 to -128.  In your above example -256 is 9 bits of 1s in 2's complement form.

Comment: The sign/magnitude representation you're looking at is sometimes called "one's complement".  It has the interesting feature that there are both positive and negative zero values.  (This is where that extra count gets lost.)

Comment: (BTW, the `11 0000 0000` answer you got above is correct.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Know this is a bit late but I wondered this too in my HW just now and looked it up.

The magnitude, given w-bits, of sign magnitude is `2^(w-1)-1`.
The decimal equivalent of `100000000` is `256`. 
Given that the number of bits is `9`, `2^(8)-1 = 255`.

So it would be impossible to store `256` given `9` bits in sign magnitude.

Answer (score -1):

It is impossible to represent `-256` in sign magnitude, with 9 bits, simply because it is not possible to represent `256` in `8` bits, (`8` bits of precision, affords `2^8 = 256` different possible values, so you can represent from `0` up to `255`, but no further).

Comment: thank you for your help. i just knew it is impossible but i also knew that there is a possible answer which is "there is no possible answer"  thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: Incorrect. The range of twos complement numbers is - 2^(n-1) to +2^(n-1)-1, which are 2^n different values. 9 bits gives you -256 to +255. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Comment: @PeterWebb I said nothing about twos complement. I specifically stated that you cannot represent -256 in **sign magnitude** predicated on the fact that the extra bit does not alter the range of the absolute values, which can only reach up to 255 given 8 bits. Please read my answer again and reconsider your downvote, I've said nothing wrong, and have answered the question precisely as it was stated.

Comment: @asQuirreL - Fair enough, it was another answer which mentioned 2's complement, and I just wrongly assumed this is the representation to be used (as this is common and makes an interesting question). Sorry, I should have responded to taytay instead. I can't undownvote you anymore. Maybe somebody would like to upvote?

Comment: @PeterWebb, no worries, OP's question was answered regardless :)